# php Laravel socket_sendto(): Unable to write to socket [1]: Operation not permitted

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to connect attendance machine ztecko via php laravel I have download the library and successfully connected via php socket on xampp localhost but as soon as i transferred to live server hostinger and I ran the url I got following error

```
socket_sendto(): Unable to write to socket [1]: Operation not permitted
```

I did a phpinfo and noticed php sockets are enabled on the hosting I am not sure what am I missing over here

Here is my attendance controller

```
public function test() {
    $zk = new ZKTeco('192.168.**.**');
    $zk->connect();  

    $usersData = $zk->getUser();
    
    foreach($usersData as $key => $user):
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($user);
        echo "</pre>";   
    endforeach;      
}
```

Reff Library that I am using for laravel

https://github.com/raihanafroz/zkteco

Please can anyone help me out what am I missing or what is wrong